# How to inference the dual form of perceptron?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, duality, machine-learning

The model of perceptron is a linear binary classifier, which is $f(x)=\mathbb{sign}(w^Tx+b)$. $x$ is the datapoint as $w$ as well as $b$ are the parameters.

The cost function of Primal Perceptron is $$\min\limits_{w,b}-\sum_{x_i\in M}{y_i\left(w^Tx_i+b\right)}$$.

Where $M$ means the datapoints set where some points is misclassified that satisfied $y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\le0$. And $y_i \in \{-1,+1\}$ is the label(target) of $x_i$, which is in the output spaces.

We can use SGD algorithm to update the parameters $w$ and $b$ with $w \leftarrow w+\eta y_ix_i,b\leftarrow \eta y_i$. Finally, we could get $w=\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_iy_ix_i,b=\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_iy_i$, if we let $\alpha_i = n_i\eta$ and the original value of $(w,b)$ is $(0,0)$. And $n_i$ means the counts where datapoint $(x_i,y_i)$ is misclassified.

So we can get the dual form of perceptron.
$$f(x)=sign\left(\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_jy_jx_j+b\right)$$.

Using that $\alpha_i \leftarrow \alpha_i+\eta,b\leftarrow b+\eta y_i$ to update.

Generally, We can get the dual form of an constrained optimization problem with Lagrange duality. But I failed to inferene the dual form of perceptron using Lagrange duality. It seems that this form is obtained directly through computing the final optimal solution. As a noob to operation reaserch, I am confused about this process. So could you guys explian the theoretical basis behind this process to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I realize this is a very late response; hopefully, it will be useful to others. Additionally, this is going to be a long answer, as I will try to work from first principles. Don't say I didn't warn you. I will solve for the (slightly more general) case when some errors are allowed as we cannot assume real-world datasets are perfectly linearly separable. However, as you will notice, the addition of an error slack variable term does not really change the derivation by much.

Finally, I only stumbled on this post because I was looking for a solution to this problem as well (but couldn't find any good sources that derived it in detail). Overall, the problem isn't too hard, but certainly not trivial either.

#### Framework for linear classifiers

Before we derive the linear program that will allow us to classify data using
perceptrons, recall the general framework for linear classifiers. Let
$\mathcal{H} = \vec{w}^T\vec{x}+b = 0$ be a hyperplane defined in $\mathbb{R}^m$
and the vector $\vec{w}$ be orthogonal to $\mathcal{H}$. Then, the line that
passes through the datapoint $\vec{x}_i$ and is orthogonal to the hyperplane is
defined by,

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{eq:orthogonal_line}
  \vec{x} - \vec{x}_i = a\vec{w}
\end{equation}

The intersection of (\ref{eq:orthogonal_line}) with the hyperplane is
$\vec{w}^T(a\vec{w} + \vec{x}_i) + b = 0$, so

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
  a = -\frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\vec{w}^T \vec{w}}
\end{equation}

meaning the projection of $\vec{x}_i$ onto a point $\vec{z} \in \mathcal{H}$ is,

\begin{equation}
\tag{3}\label{eq:projection}
  P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) = a\vec{w} + \vec{x}_i = \left( -\frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i +
  b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert^2} \right) \vec{w} + \vec{x}_i
\end{equation}

By computing the norm of (\ref{eq:projection}),

\begin{equation}
\tag{4}
  \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) \rVert = \left\lVert \left( -\frac{\vec{w}^T
  \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert^2} \right) \vec{w} + \vec{x}_i \right\rVert =
  \left| - \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert} + \vec{x}_i \right|
\end{equation}

and plugging it into the law of cosines formula,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) - \vec{x}_i \rVert^2
  &= \lVert \vec{x}_i \rVert^2 + \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) \rVert^2 - 2 \lVert
  \vec{x}_i \rVert \rVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) \lVert \cos(\theta) \\
  &= \lVert \vec{x}_i \rVert^2 + \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) \rVert^2 - 2 \lVert
  \vec{x}_i \rVert \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i) \rVert \frac{\vec{x}_i \cdot
  P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i)}{\lVert \vec{x}_i \rVert \lVert P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i)
  \rVert} \\
  &= |\vec{x}_i|^2 + \left| \left( \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w}
  \rVert} \right)^2 + (\vec{x}_i)^2 - 2 \left( \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i +
  b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert} \vec{x}_i \right) \right| - 2 \vec{x}_i \left(
  -\frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert} + \vec{x}_i \right) \\
  &= |\vec{x}_i|^2 + \left| \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert}
  \right|^2 + |\vec{x}_i|^2 - 2 \left| \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w}
  \rVert} \vec{x}_i \right| + 2 \left| \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w}
  \rVert} \vec{x}_i \right| - 2 | \vec{x}_i |^2 \\
  &= \left| \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w} \rVert} \right|^2
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

we can determine the distance of the point $\vec{x}_i$ from its projection
$P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i)$ as,

\begin{equation}
\tag{6}\label{eq:margin_distance}
  D(\vec{x}_i, P_{\vec{z}}(\vec{x}_i)) = \sqrt{\lVert P_{\vec{x}}(\vec{x}_i) -
  \vec{x}_i \rVert^2} = \sqrt{\left| \frac{\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b}{\lVert \vec{w}
  \rVert} \right|^2} = \frac{\lvert \vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b \rvert}{\lVert \vec{w}
  \rVert} = \lvert \vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b \rvert
\end{equation}

when $\lVert \vec{w} \rVert = 1$.

#### Perceptron objective + constraints

Now consider that we are given a set of
training of examples, $X = \{(\vec{x}_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^{n}$, for a binary
classification task. We say that $X$ is linearly seperable if there exists a
hyperplane $\mathcal{H}$, such that

\begin{equation}
\tag{7}
  y_i =
  \begin{cases}
    +1 & \text{if}~\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b \geq 0 \\
    -1 & \text{if}~\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b < 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here, $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a weight vector applied to each datapoint
$\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $b$ is the bias. Using
(\ref{eq:margin_distance}) we define a margin $\gamma_i$ achieved by $\vec{w}$ on
the $i$-th example as,

\begin{equation}
\tag{8}
  \gamma_i(\vec{w}) = y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) 
\end{equation}

Although any margin will work, we want to find the maximum margin achieveable on
all datapoints $\vec{x}_i$,

\begin{equation}
\tag{9}
  \gamma^* = \max_{\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m} \min_i \gamma_i(\vec{w})
\end{equation}

such that each example is classified correctly (aka $y_i = \text{sign}(\vec{w}^T
\vec{x}_i + b)$ or $\gamma_i > 0$). However, this formulation fails to take into
account that, on arbitrary real-world datasets, misclassifications are present
(whenever $\gamma_i \leq 0$); hence, we cannot assume the data is perfectly
linearly seperable. To fix this, we introduce a penalty known as the
**margin slack variable** for each example $(\vec{x}_i, y_i)$ relative to
the hyperplane $\mathcal{H}$ and the target margin $\gamma$,

\begin{equation}
\tag{10}
  \xi((\vec{x}_i, y_i), \mathcal{H}, \gamma) = \xi_i = \max\{0, \gamma -
  y_i(\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b)\}
\end{equation}

Here, $\xi_i$ measures how much a point fails to have a margin of $\gamma$ from
$\mathcal{H}$, implying that if $\xi_i > \gamma$, then $\vec{x}_i$ is
misclassified by the boundary $\mathcal{H}$. This forces the constraint $\xi_i
\geq \gamma - y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b)$, or $y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) + \xi_i
\geq \gamma$. Note that points that are correctly classified have $\xi_i = 0$.
Now that we have the objective function and constraints, we can write the
optimization problem as,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  & \underset{\vec{w},b}{\text{minimize}} && - \sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}}
  y_i(\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b) \\
  & \text{subject to} && y_i(\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b) + \xi_i \geq \gamma & 
  i=1,\dots,n \\
  &&& \xi_i \geq 0 & i=1,\dots,n
\end{aligned}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}

where instead of maximizing the number of correct classifications, we minimize
over the set of misclassified points, $\mathcal{M}$. Converting it to the
standard form,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  & \underset{\vec{w},b}{\text{minimize}} && - \sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}}
  y_i(\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b) \\
  & \text{subject to} && \gamma - \xi_i - y_i(\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + b) \leq 0 & 
  i=1,\dots,n \\
  &&& -\xi_i \leq 0 & i=1,\dots,n
\end{aligned}
\tag{12}
\end{equation}

and plugging it into the generalized Lagrangian,

\begin{equation}
\tag{13}\label{eq:lagrangian}
  L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) = -\sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}}
  y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i(\gamma - \xi_i -
  y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b)) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i \xi_i
\end{equation}

allows us to solve the dual optimization problem,

\begin{equation}
\tag{14}
  \max_{\vec\alpha,\vec\beta \colon \alpha_i,\beta_i \geq 0} L_D(\vec\alpha,\vec\beta)
\end{equation}

where $L_D(\vec\alpha,\vec\beta)$ is the Lagrangian dual, defined by,

\begin{equation}
\tag{15}\label{eq:lagrangian_dual}
  L_D(\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) = \min_{\vec{w},b,\vec\xi} L(\vec{w}, b, \vec\xi,
  \vec\alpha, \vec\beta)
\end{equation}

#### Solving the Lagrangian

To compute the simplified expression for (\ref{eq:lagrangian_dual}), we take the
derivative of $L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta)$ with respect to our
variables of interest to solve for the KKT stationary conditions,

\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{w}} L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) &=
  -\sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}} y_i \vec{x}_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i \vec{x}_i
  = 0 &&\implies -\sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}} y_i \vec{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \alpha_i y_i \vec{x}_i \tag{16}\label{eq:stationary_w} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial b} L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) &=
  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i = 0 &&\implies
  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i \tag{17}\label{eq:stationary_b} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_i} L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) &=
  - \alpha_i - \beta_i = 0 &&\implies \alpha_i + \beta_i = 0
  \tag{18}\label{eq:stationary_xi}
\end{align}

and substitute them into (\ref{eq:lagrangian}),

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  L(\vec{w},b,\vec\xi,\vec\alpha,\vec\beta)
  &= -\sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}} y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \alpha_i(\gamma - \xi_i - y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b)) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i
  \xi_i \\
  &= -\sum_{i \in \mathcal{M}} y_i\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i b +
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \gamma -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \xi_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \alpha_i y_i \vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i b -
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i \xi_i \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i \vec{w}^T \vec{x}_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i
  b + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \gamma - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i \vec{w}^T
  \vec{x}_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i b - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\alpha_i + \beta_i)
  \xi_i \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \gamma = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i (\xi_i +
  y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b)) 
\end{aligned}
\tag{19}
\end{equation}

The Lagrangian dual is therefore,

\begin{equation}
\tag{20}
  L_D(\vec\alpha,\vec\beta) = \min_{\vec{w},b,\vec{\xi}} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \alpha_i \left( \xi_i + y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) \right) \right]
\end{equation}

meaning the dual optimization problem can be written as,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  &\underset{\vec\alpha}{\text{maximize}} && \min_{\vec{w},b,\vec\xi} \left[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \left( \xi_i + y_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}_i + b) \right)
    \right] \\
  &\text{subject to} && \alpha_i \geq 0, \quad -\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i =
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i y_i & i = 1,\dots,n
\end{aligned}
\tag{21}\label{eq:dual}
\end{equation}

since the objective function in the dual form does not depend on $\vec\beta$.

#### Deriving dual form

Now that we have $\vec\alpha^*$ (the solution to the perceptron dual), we can recover the optimal $\vec{w}^*$ and $b^*$ by using the KKT conditions. From condition 5 (complementary slackness), we have that $\forall i$,

\begin{align}
  \alpha_i^* \left( \gamma - \xi_i^* - y_i({\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i + b^*) \right)
  &= 0 \tag{22}\label{eq:complementary_alpha} \\
  -\beta_i^* \xi_i^* &= 0 \tag{23}\label{eq:complementary_beta}
\end{align}

By combining (\ref{eq:stationary_xi}) and (\ref{eq:complementary_beta}), notice
that $\alpha_i^* \xi_i^* = 0$ meaning that $\xi_i^* = 0$ for any value of
$\alpha_i^*$. Then, if $\forall i, \alpha_i^* > 0$, by
(\ref{eq:complementary_alpha}),

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  y_i({\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i + b^*)      &= \gamma - \xi_i^* \\
  y_i {\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i + y_i b^*   &= \gamma \\
  y_i {\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{w}^* \vec{x}_i   &= (\gamma - y_i b^*) \vec{w}^* \\
  \frac{y_i \vec{x}_i}{\gamma - y_i b^*}  &= \vec{w}^* \\
  \frac{y_i \vec{x}_i}{\gamma \pm b^*}    &= \vec{w}^* \\
  \vec{w}^*                               &= y_i \vec{x}_i
\end{aligned}
\tag{24}
\end{equation}

where $\gamma - y_i b^* \equiv \gamma \pm b^*$ is some constant scaling factor
since $y_i \in \{-1,+1\}$. We remove $\gamma \pm b^*$ as it will not affect the
optimal of $\vec{w}$. By applying (\ref{eq:stationary_b}), the optimal normal
vector $\vec{w}^*$ becomes a linear combination taken over all training samples,

\begin{equation}
\tag{25}\label{eq:optimal_w}
  \vec{w}^* = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i \vec{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i^* y_i
  \vec{x}_i
\end{equation}

where $\alpha_i^*$ represents the number of times $\vec{x}_i$ was misclassified.
Similarly for $b^*$,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  y_i({\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i + b^*)  &= \gamma - \xi_i^* \\
  {\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i + b^*       &= \frac{\gamma}{y_i} \\
  b^*   &= \frac{\gamma}{y_i} - {\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i \\
  b^*   &= y_i - {\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_i
\end{aligned}
\tag{26}\label{eq:optimal_b}
\end{equation}

where we remove the constant $\gamma$ as it does not affect the optimal of $b$
and $\frac{1}{y_i} \equiv y_i$ since $y_i \in \{-1,+1\}$. The final decision
function is then,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \hat{y}(\vec{x}_j) &= \text{sign} ({\vec{w}^*}^T \vec{x}_j + b^*) \\
    &= \text{sign} \left[ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i^* y_i \vec{x}_i
    \right)^T \vec{x}_j + b^* \right] \\
    &= \text{sign} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i^* y_i \kappa(\vec{x}_i,
    \vec{x}_j) + b^* \right]
\end{aligned}
\tag{27}
\end{equation}

where $\vec\alpha^*$ is the solution of (\ref{eq:dual}), $b^*=y_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\alpha_i^* y_i \kappa(\vec{x}_i, \vec{x}_j)$ is solved by substituting in
(\ref{eq:optimal_w}) into (\ref{eq:optimal_b}), and $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$
represents some non-negative semidefinite kernel function between two samples
(an inner product between samples in a high-dimensional space). However, instead
of directly solving for $\vec\alpha^*$, we iteratively update $\alpha_i, b$ till
some stopping criterion is met (i.e. a certain number of iterations is reached,
or no mistakes are made for all training examples). This is performed via the
kernelized version of the algorithm [1,2],
where instead of updating $\vec{w} = \vec{w} + y_i \vec{x}_i$ (as done in the
gradient descent formulation), we update $\alpha_i = \alpha_i + 1$ for each
example $\vec{x}_i$. Note that these two procedures are equivalent, and thus,
will produce the same solution.

#### References

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_perceptron (Good overview)
2. [https://www.cs.umb.edu/~dsim/slidesPER.pdf](https://www.cs.umb.edu/%7Edsim/slidesPER.pdf) (Really useful)
3. http://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml12/slides/lecture3.pdf
4. https://ahmadzadeh.iut.ac.ir/sites/ahmadzadeh.iut.ac.ir/files//files_course/2_linear_classifiers_0.pdf
5. [https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/250B/duality-convex-handout.pdf](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edasgupta/250B/duality-convex-handout.pdf)